# Can we create a graph in QLabel? If not, what's the best way to create graphs in a dialog box?

Tags: c++, graph, qt-creator, qtcharts

I need to create a graph in my dialog box which displays as I've shown in the image. I need some guidance to move forward with this. [Example graph is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhh4x.png)

So I am developing an application in Qt creator, and I need to display a graph in a dialog box that would give better understanding of different stores and comparisons among them.

Firstly I need some guidance to know what type of Qt widget should be used and then how to create those blocks as a graph.

I am not that familiar with qt grasp, can someone help me out with this?

Comment: You could subclass `QWidget` and override its `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` method and use the `QPainter` API to draw the graph yourself, line by line; or if you want something higher level than that, you could try out the Qt Charts package:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Qt's designated widget to render images is indeed [`QLabel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html).  Just render your graph, load it up on a [`QPixmap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) by calling for example [`QPixmap::fromImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage), and then update your `QLabel` by calling [`QLabel::setPixmap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop).